# division between functions (postgresql) not work

Tags: postgresql

I have two functions that, when executed separately, return me values ​​without problem. It turns out I need to split up for each other but it's not working.

```
Function 1
select getestoque(array[19480000001], array[19480000001], '2019-03-01')
Return
183
Function 2
select avg(pel_area) from getarea(array[19480000001,19480000002], array[19480000001, 19480000002], '2019-03-01')
Return
    75.000
```

Another detail, this division needs to be done within a 3rd function, I am doing the following:

```
create or replace function getLotacao(fazenda bigint[], retiro bigint[], dataLot date, intervalo bigint)
    returns 
    table (
        totalCabecas integer,
        pesoTotal decimal(18, 6),
        UA decimal(15, 6),
        pesoMedio decimal(18, 6),
        valorMedio decimal(18, 6),
        total decimal(18, 6),
        areaHec decimal(18, 6),
        cabHec decimal(18, 6), 
        UAHA decimal(18, 6),
        areaAql decimal(18, 6),
        cabAlq decimal(18, 6), 
        UAAlq decimal(18, 6)
    ) as $$
    declare
    begin   
        for i in 0..$4 -1 loop
        return query 
        select getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
               getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
               getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450,
               getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
               getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
               getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) * (getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)),
               avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
               getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
               **(getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)**,
               avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 2.4,
               getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / (avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 2.4),
               (getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / (avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 2.4);                                                                                                       
        end loop;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    end;
    $$ language plpgsql;
```

The problem is in:

```
**(getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)**,

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"
LINE 28:      getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / avg(pel_area) fr...
```

But it's not working, can you help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Columns returned by query need to be after `SELECT` keyword and can't be listed after `FROM` keyword (mistake you did).

You can deal with this in your scenario in 3 ways:

**Change your aggregate queries to subqueries:**

```
select getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
       getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
       getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450,
       getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
       getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i),
       getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) * (getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)),
       (select avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)),
       getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / (select avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)),
       (getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / (select avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)),
       (select avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)) / 2.4,
       getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / ((select avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)) / 2.4),
       (getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) / 450) / ((select avg(pel_area) from getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i)) / 2.4);
```

**Use single `FROM`** and in there list those functions that require aggregate function used on its result. You can actually put in there all those functions.

```
select fun1,
       fun2,
       fun2 / 450,
       fun2 / fun1,
       fun3 / fun1,
       fun2 * (fun3 / fun1),
       avg(agg.pel_area),
       fun1 / avg(agg.pel_area),
       (fun2 / 450) / avg(agg.pel_area),
       avg(agg.pel_area) / 2.4,
       fun1 / (avg(agg.pel_area) / 2.4),
       (fun2 / 450) / (avg(agg.pel_area) / 2.4)
  FROM getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) AS agg
  CROSS JOIN getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) AS fun1
  CROSS JOIN getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i) AS fun2
  CROSS JOIN getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) AS fun3;
```

**RETURN NEXT**

```
declare
begin   
    for i in 0..$4 -1 loop
    totalCabecas := getestoque($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i);
    pesoTotal := getpesolotacao($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i);
    UA := pesoTotal / 450;
    pesoMedio := pesoTotal / totalCabecas;
    valorMedio := getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / totalCabecas;
    total := pesoTotal * (getvalorlotacao($1, $3::date + 1 * i) / totalCabecas);
    areaHec := avg(pel_area) FROM getarea($1, $2, $3::date + 1 * i);
    cabHec := totalCabecas / areaHec;
    UAHA := UA / areaHec;
    areaAql := areaHec / 2.4;
    cabAlq := totalCabecas / areaAql;
    UAAlq := UA / areaAql;
    RETURN NEXT;
    end loop;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I got it sorted out. For some reason there was another function with the same name and different parameters ...